# How do I implement a sequence generator using a universal shift register?

Tags: shift-register, circuits, sequence-detector

How can I implement a sequence generator that generates the following sequence
0000
1000
0001
0011
0110
1101
1110
1111 using a universal shift register? The shift register I need to use is the 74LS194 model shown below where the inputs S1, S0 controls the shift mode.

If (S1,S0) = (0,0), then the current value is locked to the next state.
If (1,0), it's shift to right. If (0,1), it's shift to left, and (1,1) indicates parallel loading from the parallel data inputs.

I think this would be a simple question if the requirement was just using flip flops of my choice and not the shift register, but with this requirement I don't know where to start. Even though I draw 4 karnaugh maps for each digit I don't seem to grasp a clue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

[image: Universal shift register]

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the output sequence to be serial or parallel 4 bits at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following representation of the sequence:

```
      0000
     1000
      0001
       0011
        0110
         1101
        1110
       1111
```

This should help you visualize how the sequence could be generated through a sequence of left/right shifts.

For each state, write out the previous state, and the required shift direction and shift-in value. These will be the inputs and outputs for your control circuitry. From that, you should be able to generate a Karnaugh map and the required logic.

(Every state transition is a left or right shift -- `S1,S0` will always be `01` or `10`. You do not need the parallel load mode for this circuit.)